# Symfony - get targetPath information

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have an application that provide to User an activation of service under a link. When user go to route:

> www.mysite.com/user/active_service/1

Symfony check if the User are logged, if not redirect to login/register page. But I want customized this welcome page with the kind of service requested (id=1 in the route).

How can I get that information in the login/register action?

Comment: Could you please clarify  what you want to do on which site? Do you want to display something like "Welcome *USER*" when the user is logged in?

Comment: I want display "Welcome User, for activate service 1 log in or register", customize with the information of the service requested in the initial route

Comment: When you redirect just pass the '1' value off to the route that you redirect it to.

Comment: But the redirect in symfony are made automatically, so I can't control the route or param before redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do with this:

```
$targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.main.target_path'); 

if(preg_match("/\/match\/[0-9]+$/", $targetPath))
{
   //do somethings
};
```

and adding a pregmatch to targetPath, for know if the request is the request for that I want customize my welcome view.